# Interpolating dates across N python Lists

Tags: python, list, date, dictionary, interpolation

I am attempting to write a date interpolation algorithm for a dictionary:

- each dictionary entry has N keys
- Each key for the entry has a corresponding list of dates
- No dates can be duplicated across the key lists
- If I was to flatten all the lists for an entry after processing I would end up with a continuous list of daily dates
- interpolation should only be between dates that do not appear in other lists (see below simplified example

Ex. D =  {"Entry":{"list1":[1,2,9,12],"list2":[4,6]}}

Dfinal = {"Entry":{"list1":[1,2,3,7,8,9,10,11,12],"list2":[4,5,6]}}

In my sample code I merge all the lists into one, sort that list and then get the index of each of the dates which I then can interpolate between if the outer index is is the same ie. [0][1] [0][2] the problem I am having is figuring out how to switch and interpolate on another list when I hit a date that exists in another list. I am almost there I just am not sure how to finish this its quite the puzzle!

```
from datetime import date, timedelta as td
import datetime
import numpy as np
import calendar

#Interpolate Dates
def datesBetween(StartDate,EndDate):
    dates = []
    year1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(StartDate),'%d%b%Y').year
    year2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(EndDate),'%d%b%Y').year
    Month1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(StartDate),'%d%b%Y').month
    Month2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(EndDate),'%d%b%Y').month
    day1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(StartDate),'%d%b%Y').day
    day2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(EndDate),'%d%b%Y').day
    d1 = date(year1, Month1, day1)
    d2 = date(year2, Month2, day2)
    delta = d2 - d1
    dates.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(str(StartDate),'%d%b%Y').strftime('%d%b%Y'))
    d0 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(StartDate),'%d%b%Y')
    for i in range(delta.days):
        d0 += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        dates.append(d0.strftime('%d%b%Y'))
    return dates

#Sort Dates
def date_key(a):
    a = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, '%d%b%Y').date()
    return a


dates1 = ['28aug2017', '29aug2017', '30aug2017', '31aug2017', '01sep2017', '12sep2017','13sep2017', '14sep2017','20sep2017', '21sep2017', '25sep2017', '26sep2017','27sep2017', '28sep2017', '29sep2017', '02oct2017']

dates2 = ['05sep2017', '06sep2017', '07sep2017', '08sep2017', '11sep2017', '03oct2017']

dates3 = [ '15sep2017', '18sep2017', '19sep2017']


master = [dates1,dates2,dates3]

conc = []
for lst in master:
    conc = conc + lst

sortedDates = sorted(conc,key=date_key)

indexMain = []
indexSub = []

for d in sortedDates:
    indexMain.append(next((i for i, sublist in enumerate(master) if str(d) in sublist), -1))
    indexSub.append(next((sublist for sublist in master if str(d) in sublist)).index(str(d)))


#interpolation of the respective lists
i = 0
while i < len(indexMain)-1:

    d1 = master[indexMain[i]][indexSub[i]]
    d2 = master[indexMain[i+1]][indexSub[i+1]]

    if indexMain[i] == indexMain[i+1]:
        temp = datesBetween(str(d1),str(d2))
        for val in temp:
            if val not in master[indexMain[i]]:
                master[indexMain[i]].append(str(val))

    if indexMain[i] != indexMain[i+1]:
        temp = datesBetween(str(d1),str(d2))
        for val in temp[:len(temp)-1]:
            if val not in master[indexMain[i]]:
                master[indexMain[i]].append(str(val))

    i += 1    

print(master[0])
print(master[1])
print(master[2])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

```
from datetime import date, timedelta as td
import datetime
import numpy as np
import calendar

#Interpolate Dates
def datesBetween(StartDate,EndDate):
    dates = []
    year1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(StartDate),'%d%b%Y').year
    year2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(EndDate),'%d%b%Y').year
    Month1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(StartDate),'%d%b%Y').month
    Month2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(EndDate),'%d%b%Y').month
    day1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(StartDate),'%d%b%Y').day
    day2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(EndDate),'%d%b%Y').day
    d1 = date(year1, Month1, day1)
    d2 = date(year2, Month2, day2)
    delta = d2 - d1
    dates.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(str(StartDate),'%d%b%Y').strftime('%d%b%Y'))
    d0 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(StartDate),'%d%b%Y')
    for i in range(delta.days):
        d0 += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        dates.append(d0.strftime('%d%b%Y'))
    return dates

#Sort Dates
def date_key(a):
    a = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, '%d%b%Y').date()
    return a


dates1 = ['28aug2017', '31aug2017', '01sep2017']

dates2 = ['30aug2017']

dates3 = [ '03sep2017', '05sep2017']


master = [dates1,dates2,dates3]

conc = []
for lst in master:
    conc = conc + lst

sortedDates = sorted(conc,key=date_key)

indexMain = []
indexSub = []

for d in sortedDates:
    indexMain.append(next((i for i, sublist in enumerate(master) if str(d) in sublist), -1))
    indexSub.append(next((sublist for sublist in master if str(d) in sublist)).index(str(d)))

i = 0
print(len(indexMain)-1)
while i < len(indexMain)-1:
    d1 = master[indexMain[i]][indexSub[i]]
    d2 = master[indexMain[i+1]][indexSub[i+1]]
    if indexMain[i] == indexMain[i+1]:
        temp = datesBetween(str(d1),str(d2))
        for val in temp:   
            if str(val).lower() not in master[indexMain[i]]:
                master[indexMain[i]].append(str(val).lower())
        i += 1  
    else:
        temp = datesBetween(str(d1),str(d2))
        temp = temp[:len(temp)-1]
        for val in temp:
            if str(val).lower() not in master[indexMain[i]]:
                master[indexMain[i]].append(str(val).lower())        
        i += 1  



print(sorted(master[0],key=date_key))
print(sorted(master[1],key=date_key))
print(sorted(master[2],key=date_key))
```